# How to query a lookup table using a list?

Tags: c#, linq

Given the classes below, I want to be able to use a List of ids to return designs that have the AttributeId of 1 or 3 in the DesignAttribute table.

```
public class Design
{
    public int DesignId { get; set; }
    public string DesignName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DesignAttribute> DesignAttributes { get; set;}
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }
}

public class DesignAttribute
{
    public int DesignAttributeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Design Design { get; set; }
    public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
}
```

A design can have 1 or more attributes, for example

Design Table

```
DesignId    DesignName
1           Design A
2           Design B
3           Design C
```

Attribute Table

```
AttributeId     AttributeName
1               Light
2               Dark
3               Demo
```

DesignAttribute Table

```
DesignAttributeId   Design_DesignId     Attribute_AttributeId
1                   1                   1               Design A is Light 
2                   1                   3               Design A is also a Demo 
3                   2                   2               Design B is Dark
4                   3                   1               Design C is Light
```

I've got the following code

```
//attributes list = "[1,3]  I want any designs that have  Light OR Demo attributes"
public List<Design> FilterDesigns(List<string> attributes)
{
    //sudo code as i'm not sure how to structure this.
    var designs = db.Designs.Where(i => i.DesignAttributes 
    WHERE     DesignAttributes.AttributeId is in the list of attributes passed into the method) 
}
```

So i'd hopefully end up with a list of 2 items containing the designs Design A and Design C, as they both have an ID against the Attribute Id 1 and 3 in the DesignAttribute lookup table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var designs = db.Designs.Where(design => 
                  design.DesignAttributes.Any(designAttribute => 
                   attributes.Contains(designAttribute.Attribute.AttributeId)))
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Design> designTable = new List<Design>() {
                new Design() { DesignId = 1,  DesignName = "A"},
                new Design() { DesignId = 2,  DesignName = "B"},
                new Design() { DesignId = 3,  DesignName = "C"}
            };

            List<Attribute> attributeTable = new List<Attribute>() {
                new Attribute() { AttributeId = 1, AttributeName = "Light"},
                new Attribute() { AttributeId = 2, AttributeName = "Dark"},
                new Attribute() { AttributeId = 3, AttributeName = "Demo"}
            };
            List<DesignAttribute> designAttributeTable = new List<DesignAttribute>() {
                new DesignAttribute() { DesignAttributeId = 1, DesignId = 1, AttributeId = 1},
                new DesignAttribute() { DesignAttributeId = 2, DesignId = 1, AttributeId = 3},
                new DesignAttribute() { DesignAttributeId = 3, DesignId = 2, AttributeId = 2},
                new DesignAttribute() { DesignAttributeId = 4, DesignId = 3, AttributeId = 1}
            };

            var results = (from dattbl in designAttributeTable
                           join dttbl in designTable on dattbl.DesignId equals dttbl.DesignId
                           join attbl in attributeTable on dattbl.AttributeId equals attbl.AttributeId
                           select new { designName = dttbl.DesignName, attributeName = attbl.AttributeName }).ToList();


        }

    }
    public class Design
    {
        public int DesignId { get; set; }
        public string DesignName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<DesignAttribute> DesignAttributes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attribute
    {
        public int AttributeId { get; set; }
        public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    }

    public class DesignAttribute
    {
        public int DesignAttributeId { get; set; }
        public int DesignId { get; set; }
        public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this query:

```
  var ids = new List<int> { 1, 3 };
  var designs = db.DesignAttributes
                .Where(m => ids.Contains(m.DesignAttributeId))
                .Select(p => p.Design)
                .ToList();
```

It will query `DesignAttributes` where `DesignAttributeId` are present in list `ids`. Than it will select `Designs`.